# Is it possible to inspect an individual node object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nsolid

I've taken a snapshot of my node app in nsolid and can see that Object 549949 has a very large [retained size](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-101?hl=en).

Is there any way I can drill down into this Object and see it's keys/values and dependent objects?

[image]

**Edit:** thanks @edsadr ! For those interested, the object was the Maxmind GeoIP database:

[image]

Comment: I am glad it helped ... let me know if you have any other question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To inspect the object in deep I would suggest to use Chrome dev tools, snapshots taken by N|Solid console can be downloaded to your local drive and then can be loaded there.

If you wish to download the profile for a better analysis simply click the **download snapshot** button, then open **Google Chrome**, open **Chrome developer tools**, go to the **Profiles** tab, right-click in the tab pane and select **Load profile**, select the dump file and click Open, then you can inspect the heap snapshot in deep.